# What is the result of a fielder jumping from outside the boundary to catch a ball?

Tags: rules, cricket

Suppose that a fielder is running to catch the ball or field the ball and is running towards the boundary.

Eventually or willfully the fielder crosses the boundary rope before he is going to touch the ball in any case.

Then he jumps from outside the boundary rope and fields/catches the ball and sends it back to the other fielder while in the air.

Will the runs be given for this case? Because when the ball reached the boundary, the fielder was not in the field as he had crossed the rope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the runs will be given for this. But not a boundary will be given, the runs which were taken by the batsmen running between the wickets will be awarded for the batsman.

The moment when the ball touches fielder will be noticed for deciding it a boundary or not. Touching the boundary rope or passing the boundary rope before or after getting touch with the ball will not cause any effect on the runs.

The best example I can provide you is Bollinger of Chennai Super kings took an excellent catch for Yousuf Pathan at IPL 2010 at the boundary rope.

See this youtube [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=juV_1d1-yNA) for reference

Comment: This is an an entirely different answer to that given by @silverrahul - but who has won more votes. So who is correct.? Can you comment on their answer?

Comment: @WS2, yes ICC has changed the rules now.

Answer (score 6):

The situation described will be a boundary 6 i.e. six runs will be awarded to batting team.

The relevant law is as follows

> **19.5.2** A fielder who is not in contact with the ground is considered to be grounded beyond the boundary if his/her final contact with the ground, before his/her first contact with the ball after it has been delivered by the bowler, was not entirely within the boundary.

From the question,

> Then he jumps from **outside** the boundary rope and fields/catches the ball and sends it back to the other fielder while in the air

his final contact with the ground before his first contact with the ball was outside the boundary.

When he first touched the ball, he was grounded outside the boundary (even though he was in the air at that moment). Hence, this will be judged as a boundary 6.