# How far can a fielder go to stop a six?

Tags: rules, cricket

This is an extension of [this question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2705/what-will-be-action-for-this) asked earlier.

Is there a limit that the fielders cannot cross when taking catches or saving runs for the team?

For example, if the batsman hits far enough, lets say in the third row of the seats, then is there any rule to restrict the fielder from entering the crowd, collecting the ball air-borne, and throwing it back into field (if it is feasible)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a fielder is past the boundary rope it doesn't matter whether they are airborne or not, it is still a six. If the player jumps *from within the field of play*, catches the ball and throws it back before hitting the ground, then they will have prevented the six from scoring (and if they or a team mate can then catch the ball again before it hits the ground the batter will be out).

Once the fielder has stepped across the boundary line, if they touch the ball then it will be a six.

Comment: Note that this answer has been very slightly superseded by the October 2013 law changes - it is only for the first contact with the ball that the fielder must have jumped from within the field of play. Second and subsequent touches can be made by fielders jumping from anywhere. For example, see [Glenn Maxwell's catch in the 4th Eng vs Aus ODI, 2015](http://www.espncricinfo.com/the-ashes-2015/content/story/920039.html).